# test return value of transaction

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, assembly

`contractA`

```js
function test() internal {
  stateVariable = 20;
  uint num = 20;
  assembly {
     mstore(0x00, num)
     return(0x00, 0x20)
  }
}
```

How do I test the `return` ? I am using `hardhat` , but i don't think it changes anything.

Step 1: I should create another contract `contractB` which is a mock and which is the child of the `contractA`. This way, I can make this `contractB`'s function public and it will include the internal function - `test`.

After this, I'd appreciate if I could hear your opinions what could be the best way to make sure to test this.

Comment: That's the only way to test internal function that I'm aware of.

Comment: yes, but how do I test `contractB's` public function ? when calling a transaction from javascript, it doesn't return the value..

Comment: You could make B's functions that calls `test` generate an event with the returned value. The tricky part is that `return` ends the whole call that invokes `test` so you need some kind of indirection like using .call or .delegatecall to invoke test.